# React: How can I stop BarcodeScannerComponent when I get the result

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem to use React BarcodeScannerComponent. How can I stop the scan process after return result? By console.log, it return correct result and keep scan, how can I remove focus on the component so it can stop scanning ?

There is my Component, Thanks

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import BarcodeScannerComponent from "react-webcam-barcode-scanner";

export default class GetCodeEditor extends Component<any, any> {
 constructor(props: any) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     value: this.props.value || "",
     scann: this.props.scann || false,
     data: []
   }
 }
 getValue() {
   if (this.props.value === null && this.state.value === "") {
     return null;
   }
   return this.state.value;
 }

 isPopup() {
   return !this.state.scann;
 }

 render() {
   return (
       <BarcodeScannerComponent
         width={500}
         height={500}
         onUpdate={(err, result: any) => {
           if (result) {
             this.setState({
               scann: true,
               value: result.text,
             });
             this.isPopup();
             console.log("Test:" + scann + " "  + result.text);
           }
           else {
             this.setState({
               scann: false,
               value: 'Not Found',
             });
           }}}
       />
   );}
}
```

Comment: Looks like it's just on when mounted. You can unmount `BarcodeScannerComponent` component when finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not render Scanner once you got value, try following code

```
import React, { Component, useState } from "react";
import BarcodeScannerComponent from "react-webcam-barcode-scanner";

export default class GetCodeEditor extends Component<any, any> {
 constructor(props: any) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
     value: this.props.value || "",
     scann: this.props.scann || false,
     data: []
   }
 }
 getValue() {
   if (this.props.value === null && this.state.value === "") {
     return null;
   }
   return this.state.value;
 }

 isPopup() {
   return !this.state.scann;
 }

 render() {
   return this.state.value || (
       <BarcodeScannerComponent
         width={500}
         height={500}
         onUpdate={(err, result: any) => {
           if (result) {
             this.setState({
               scann: true,
               value: result.text,
             });
             this.isPopup();
             console.log("Test:" + scann + " "  + result.text);
           }
           else {
             this.setState({
               scann: false,
               value: 'Not Found',
             });
           }}}
       />
   );}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I want. However it work on PC but fail on iphone and ipad. I guess It request the access right on cam. any one can help ...